# Control img's border perimeter by time countdown - from full circle, through partial arc, to nothing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I use html, css, angularjs in the front.
I've got an img which in the initial state is surrounded with a full circle of a thick border. I start a countdown of a minute. I would like the border to get partially disappeared as the time goes down.

For example, after the first second only 59/60 of the perimeter of the border is shown, after the second one only 58/60 is shown, ..., after 30 seconds there's only a half of a circle and so on, until it gets totally disappeared.

In addition, if it's possible, I would like the transitions to be smooth.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a combination of [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) for conditionnal CSS on your case AND css transition.

See for example this example of a smooth transition that is for a 5s for an element to be half visible

```
#myTransition {
    opacity: .5;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: I know about css transitions, but that's not the point at all. Please read the question again, the main part of the question is how to make part of the arc of the border to disappear every second or every certain interval of time... and you are writing about opacity transition? If you make the transition on the border-color prop it will be applied on the whole perimeter of the border not on a partial arc of it.. In addition, I don't understand why the question was down voted?? I demand a clarification from the person who down voted that!